# How to return tuples and count from list using list comprehension

Tags: python, list, python-3.x, list-comprehension

I have a function which, using list comprehension, returns the list elements in caps, and counts each element.

```
def wordlengths(mywords):
    upperword = [word.upper() for word in mywords]
    lenword = [len(i) for i in mywords]
    return upperword, lenword
print(wordlengths(["The", "quick", "brown", "fox"]))
```

This returns:

```
(['THE', 'QUICK', 'BROWN', 'FOX'], [3, 5, 5, 3])
```

but i need it to return paired tuples like this:

```
[("THE", 3), ("QUICK", 5), ("BROWN", 5), ("FOX", 3)]
```

I tried to use the `zip()` method with no success. How do I go about doing this?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You can use [`zip()`](https://docs.python.org/3/library/functions.html#zip):

```
def wordlengths(mywords):
    upperword = [word.upper() for word in mywords]
    lenword = [len(i) for i in mywords]
    return list(zip(upperword, lenword))
```

But, why don't construct the list in a single iteration:

```
def wordlengths(mywords):
    return [(word.upper(), len(word)) for word in mywords]
```